# Jquery Method not found

Tags: jquery, html

I'm changing the following script in order to work with jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp.

```
drag = function(ev) {
        console.log("started drag", ev.target);
        console.log('$(ev.target).parent()[0]',  $(ev.target).parent()[0]);
        console.log(' $(ev.target).parent()[0].attr(\'id\')',  $(ev.target).parent()[0].attr('id'));


    }
```

Can someone explain why I get an Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in the last log? (attr method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
$(ev.target).parent().attr('id')
```

The error is raising because `.attr()` is not a native javascript function.

And by the way, it is the time for you to read [**www.w3fools.com**](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: Yep thanks. Why do you sometimes need to access the first element [0] of the parent and why sometimes you can directly access it (in this case)?

Comment: You access the first element (or any element for that matter) to get the DOM node instead of the JQuery object

Comment: @Vincent `.attr()` is a function belongs to jquery object. basically the .parent() would return a jquery object. If you want to access the javascript functionality through that jquery object, you have to access the js object by jquery object's first element.

Comment: big up for response and w3fools link